# creating a computed value in items in an array using knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I am trying to get some items in an array to update as function of a timer event. But I can't wrap my mind about how to do in in knockout... more I feel a bit knocked-out myself.

The Problem I think is simple, perhaps my approach is wrong, or there simply is something I don't get.

To be a bit more detailed:

The items in the array each represent a time since 'something', to prevent reloading from the server, as you can see, I have bound to the ko.computed(display) function I have defined, which was supposed to take the items.timeElapsed and add the time since the page was loaded, self.moreTimeElapsed()

The html:

```
<div>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: counted">
        <li><span data-bind="text: name"></span> - <span data-bind="text: display"></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the ViewModel

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.email = 'someone@example.com';

        var d = new Date();
        self.startTime = d.getTime();
        self.moreTimeElapsed = ko.observable(0);

        var items = [{"name":"counter1","timeElapsed":168},{"name":"counter2","timeElapsed":162}];
        for (i = 0; i < items.length; ++i)
        {
            items[i].display = ko.computed(function ()
            {
                return items[i].timeElapsed + self.moreTimeElapsed();
            })
        }
        self.counted = ko.observableArray(items);
        self.updateCounters = function () {
            var d = new Date();
            self.moreTimeElapsed(d.getTime() - self.startTime);
        }
        setInterval(self.updateCounters, 3000);
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel());
    function Reload() {
        location.reload(true);
    }
</script>
```

Any hint or ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with the counter 'i' going out of scope.

i wrapped the code in a closure and that solved the problem

```
    var items = [{"name":"counter1","timeElapsed":1706},{"name":"counter2","timeElapsed":1700}];

    var attachDisplayFunc = function(item) {
        item.display = ko.computed(function () {
            return item.timeElapsed + self.moreTimeElapsed();
        })
    }

    for (i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        attachDisplayFunc(items[i]);
    }
    self.counted = ko.observableArray(items);
```

So.. is there any way to get notified when making errors as this?

Comment: Well... no. But I am glad that you have solved your problem by defining an isolated function. It's much better than using the stupid IIFE hack and this is exactly why the `let` keyword which is introduced to solve this problem is needless.